# Sub query max date

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have 5 tables: 
employee, person_analys, criteria, assignment, and pay

I want to show :

```
employee_id and full_name from employee,
date_from and date_to from person_analys,
segment1 and segment2 from criteria,
efective_end_date from assignment,
salary from pay
```

I want to show every employee_id and only show 1 row in 1 day 
and take the last date (max date from effective_end_date). 
date_from and date_to is describe for day.

Example :

```
employee_id    full_name    date_from    date_to     segment1    segment2    effective_end_date    salary
11111        aaa        01-Jan-17    01-Jan-17    11:00        17:00        02-Jan-17        1000
11111        aaa        01-Jan-17    01-Jan-17    11:00        17:00        01-Jan-17        2000
```

I want to show only 1 row each employee and each day based on max effective end date like this :

```
employee_id    full_name    date_from    date_to     segment1    segment2    effective_end_date    salary
11111        aaa        01-Jan-17    01-Jan-17    11:00        17:00        02-Jan-17        1000
```

please help me.
I have tried but the where condition is not working and still show all data.
thank you :)

Comment: Mysql or oracle ?

Comment: Oracle. But still not working. Effective_end_date still show : 31-Dec-12 but i have data in 17-Oct-17.

Comment: I guess your `effective_end_date` data type is `varchar2`. Then test the edited version of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use subquery behind `FROM`

```
with join_of_tables as (
  select TO_DATE(effective_end_date as date, 'DD-MON-YY') as effective_end_date, ...
  -- here you should have a join of your tables
)
select e.*
from join_of_tables e
join (
    select employee_id, max(effective_end_date) max_effective_end_date   
    from join_of_tables
    group by employee_id
) t on e.employee_id= t.employee_id and
       e.effective_end_date = t.max_effective_end_date
```

If the datatype of `effective_end_date` is `varchar2` then you should cast it to date first (`TO_DATE` function in my example).